# search in object tree depending on depth value

Tags: javascript, json, tree

I have an object that has random keys and values of other objects where the last depth of the tree has an id.

I want a create a function that takes a string and depth to get the child object depending on those two values

for example, I have the data like that:

```
var treeObj = {
    "random key1": {
        "random key11": {
            "random key11": {
                "random key11": {
                    id: 25,
                    count: 364
                },
                "random key12": {
                    id: 52,
                    count: 644
                },
                "random key13": {
                    id: 5,
                    count: 664
                },
                "random key14": {
                    id: 5,
                    count: 624
                }
            }
        },
        "random key2": {
            "random key21": {
                "random key21": {
                    id: 56,
                    count: 64
                }
            },
            "random key22": {
                "random key221": {
                    id: 56,
                    count: 64
                },
                "random key222": {
                    id: 35,
                    count: 64
                }
            },
        }
    },
    "other random key":{
        "different random key":{
            "different random key": {
                "different random key1": {
                    id: 75,
                    count: 664
                },
                "different random key2": {
                    id: 57,
                    count: 624
                },
                "different random key3": {
                    id: 50,
                    count: 654
                },
            },
        },
        "different random key2":{
            "different random key2": {
                "different random key21": {
                    id: 15,
                    count: 64
                },
            },
        }
    }
}
```

what I want is a function like:

get_child_obj('random key1', 0)

should return this:

```
{
    "random key11": {
        "random key11": {
            "random key11": {
                id: 25,
                count: 364
            },
            "random key12": {
                id: 52,
                count: 644
            },
            "random key13": {
                id: 5,
                count: 664
            },
            "random key14": {
                id: 5,
                count: 624
            }
        }
    },
    "random key2": {
        "random key21": {
            "random key21": {
                id: 56,
                count: 64
            }
        },
        "random key22": {
            "random key221": {
                id: 56,
                count: 64
            },
            "random key222": {
                id: 35,
                count: 64
            }
        },
    }
}
```

and a function like that:

```
get_child_obj('different random key', 2)
```

should return this:

```
{
    "different random key1": {
        id: 75,
        count: 664
    },
    "different random key2": {
        id: 57,
        count: 624
    },
    "different random key3": {
        id: 50,
        count: 654
    },
}
```

and a function like that:

```
get_child_obj('random key12', 3)
```

should return this:

```
{
    id: 52,
    count: 644
}
```

please note that for each depth the key is unique.

Comment: Please, consider adding what you have tried so far... that will be a good signal you have made some effort for yourself and not just asking someone to do your work...

Comment: I have been trying since two days without having the desired answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could take a recursive approach by handing over the object for seraching and by decrementing the depth for each nested level.

If `depth` is zero return the wanted property, otherwise iterate the values of the object and check if the nested object contains the wanted property.

```js
function getChild(object, key, depth) {
    var result;
    return depth
        ? (Object.values(object).some(v => result = getChild(v, key, depth - 1)), result)
        : object[key];
}

var tree = { "random key1": { "random key11": { "random key11": { "random key11": { id: 25, count: 364 }, "random key12": { id: 52, count: 644 }, "random key13": { id: 5, count: 664 }, "random key14": { id: 5, count: 624 } } }, "random key2": { "random key21": { "random key21": { id: 56, count: 64 } }, "random key22": { "random key221": { id: 56, count: 64 }, "random key222": { id: 35, count: 64 } } } }, "other random key": { "different random key": { "different random key": { "different random key1": { id: 75, count: 664 }, "different random key2": { id: 57, count: 624 }, "different random key3": { id: 50, count: 654 } } }, "different random key2": { "different random key2": { "different random key21": { id: 15, count: 64 } } } } };

console.log(getChild(tree, 'random key1', 0));
console.log(getChild(tree, 'different random key', 2));
console.log(getChild(tree, 'random key12', 3));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: There should be an `Array.prototype.findValue` for siuations like these ...